# Is There Any Chance Deleted User Id Is Used Again When Registering New Another Account In Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good day!, i just want to make sure of this thing.
Is there any chance when we deleted an user in wordpress, and then the deleted user id is used again when a new another account is registered? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ID` column in the SQL `wp_users` table has the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute by default, meaning that unless you explicitly change the ID value for an entry, there will never be a duplicate ID used and it will always increment by 1 from the previous ID.

Comment: Allright, thank you for the information!

Comment: going to have to check what happens when the ID you delete happens to be the very last one in the column...